# 404 - Not Found when I try to browse to my local WebServer using the IP

Tags: macos, laravel, apache, npm, http-status-code-404

So I'm developing responsive websites and obviously need to test these via phones and tablets and it used to work fine, up until yesterday, after I tried installing js frameworks like npm.

For some reason, when I browse to my local testing using the ip it get:

```
404 - Not Found
```

I've been used to using:

```
http://192.168.0.2/filename.php
```

I've tried:

```
http://192.168.0.2:8080/filename.php
```

...still get 404 - Not Found
I've restarted Apache and checked the the port is correct, and it is.

```
Listen 80
```

This happened before when I installed Laravel and Valet, but not long after that I had to wipe my Mac due to work and it started working again with a fresh install.

Am I missing something in Apache? does npm and Laravel mess with the Apache settings?

Locally, everything works fine. I can browse to localhost/filename.php directly using Mac with PHP and MySQL talking to each other, albeit after using Homebrew to install MySQL, PHP connections now only accepts 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost.

I've set all the permissions to "everyone" there should be no access issues.

I've noticed another oddity with Firefox Dev Ed too. When I've been using Valet or Gulp, it stops connecting and give a Cannt connect to server error, but Safari and Chrome seem to work ok.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd be happy to give it a go!

Comment: Please show your Apache config and file structure.

Comment: stupid idea> Are you sure the wanted server/service is listening on the port you are using? You said you installed some new stuff. Also check the hosts file of your OS..

Comment: So, I've found it's not the Apache httpd.conf thats causing the issue. I've another mac that has a working service and I've managed to copy the httpd.conf file across, restarted apachectl and I'm still getting 404.

Comment: So, the stupid idea>... the hosts file is unchanged so can rule that out

Answer (score 0):

All fixed! It was Larvel's Valet installation that was causing the issue, as suspected.

So, looked at the brew Cellar directory in /usr/local/Cellar, but it wasn't actually in there. Then opened up Terminal and typed:

```
valet install
```

Then ran valet by typing:

```
valet
```

Then uninstalled valet by typing:

```
uninstalled valet
```

Then restarted Apache2 by typing:

```
sudo apachectl restart
adding password
```

Booted up the browser and browsed to `localhost/info.php` which holds the line `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and HAPPY DAYS :)